# Cannot Change Navigation Bar Tint Color iOS7 with MapView

Tags: objective-c, colors, mkmapview, uinavigationbar, ios7

Has anyone found that if you change the navigation bar tint color on a view with a **MKMapView** that you cannot change it? For example, let's say you set the following code in your *AppDelegate* to change the color to green:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
```

Any *uiviewcontroller* that has a *MKMapView* the bar tint color stays black and no matter what I do, I cannot change it. All other uiviewcontrollers change with no problems. And yes, I have already tried to force the change by placing the code directly in the univiewcontroller .m file but still will not change.

Anyone else have this issue and was able to fix it?

Comment: It sounds like your map view might not extend up under the navigation bar. Post your layout code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the work-around I end up with. Put these on all view controllers:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
}
```

I monkey patch ([swizzling](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2013/02/20/monkey-patching-ios-with-objective-c-categories-part-iii-swizzling/)) these into UIViewControllers and that's it. If you have any subclass of UIViewController which override `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear`, just make sure you send the super class these messages as well.

Note: This has the side effect of a brief flash when translucency is kicking in front of your eye, though.